# How to tell if an app is going to get suspended from QML

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm developing a game for Ubuntu Touch that needs to go in a "pause" state when the user goes away from the app to another. How do I get this.

I tried to see if the visibility of the MainView changes, but it doesn't. Couldn't find it in the cookbook nor in the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There an application property in the qt imported namespace which has a state that can be bound to:

```
Connections {
    target: Qt.application
    onStateChanged:
        if(Qt.application.state !== Qt.ApplicationActive) {
            // Pauze the game here
        }
}
```

The documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#application-prop) says the following:

### application.state

> Qt.ApplicationActive - The application is the top-most and focused application, and the user is able to interact with the application.

But this is also issued with swiping from the top or left.

On the desktop, this is also issued when you re-size the window, which I'd consider a bug.

---

There is also:

> Qt.ApplicationSuspended - The application is suspended and not visible to the user. On mobile platforms, the application typically enters this state when the user returns to the home screen or switches to another application. While in this state, the application should ensure that the user perceives it as always alive and does not lose his progress, saving any persistent data. The application should cease all activities and be prepared for code execution to stop. While suspended, the application can be killed at any time without further warnings (for example when low memory forces the OS to purge suspended applications).

But this doesn't seem to work. I've reported a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qtubuntu/+bug/1504776). Please mark if it also affects you.

Comment: This cannot seem to differentiate between something coming over the top of the app on the phone (eg. swipe from the left or the top) and being truly suspended by being sent a SIGSTOP (which happens when the application has been moved away from the foreground or the screen is locked). The [QML documentation for the application property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#application-prop) defines `Qt.ApplicationSuspended` but it seems that the app never sees itself in this state on Ubuntu, which is unfortunate. So `Qt.application.active` will have to do - thanks.